# IntelliJ Terminal CTRL+C does not work

Tags: windows, git, intellij-idea, terminal

When using IntelliJs integrated terminal - for example with git - sometimes my CTRL + C keystrokes don't make to the terminal. For example the current line is not aborted.

What can I do as this behaviour is very annoying.

Comment: Also see this offical bug in Jetbrains bugtracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166643

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I had `git for Windows` installed anyway I just replaced the terminal used by IntelliJ from `cmd.exe` (which is the default on windows) to `bash.exe` supplied by `git for Windows` (which is `cygwin` btw)

To change it for all projects go to `File >> Other Settings >> Default Settings` and then `Tools >> Terminal`. (see screenshot)

In the shell path field set the following line:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i
```

Please make sure git is installed at the proper localtion or adjust the path (for example if you have the 32bit version of git installed)

[image: screenshot of the windows to change the option]

Using bash instead of cmd, the problem does not occour for me. Plus the bash supports some commands that cmd does not support, which is kinda nice when been used to a linux environment.

EDIT 2020-09-30: In latest Intellij versions the Terminal is a project-level setting and can be changed here:

[image: new version is located under "new projects settings"]

Comment: Thank you very much. It drove me crazy to have a Powershell with clear (and other Linux commands) but not working Ctrl+C. Very elegant solution.

Comment: On recent IntelliJ version, configuration is located at `Settings > Tools > Terminal`

Comment: Thank you - my issue was that I used the `sh.exe` instead of the `bash.exe`

Answer (score 0):

**Sometimes it could be because of vim emulator just turn it off**

- Go to **Tools**
- **Deselect** Vim Emulator

Answer (score 0):

Because Vim mode is checked,

Tools, Vim Emulator, there will be a √ in front of it, just cancel it, as shown in the figure:[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqDFh.png)

I hope i can help u.